# How to get the filename from the full path and store in an object property in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My initial problem was to store only the filename from the full path on an object and I did find the answers to that online but I had problem storing the same in a property of an object.

Here is a piece of code that I have written. Hopefully my problem would be clear.

```
let song = {
                  name: document.getElementById('title').value,//Line 1
                  artist: document.getElementById('yr').value,//Line 2
                  path: function () {//Line 3
                  var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                  return filename;
                  }
```

This whole code is inside a function which is called and the user is asked to choose a file from his computer. Now what my problem is in Line3,I need to store the filename only from the fullpath (Example: 'example.mp3'), inside the 'path' property of the object 'song'.
This is what was getting saved in 'path' once I run the code-

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCIpu.png)

Please help me in solving this .
Thanks!

Comment: If you're defining `path` as a function, then at some point you need to execute that function with `()` in order to access its return value. Currently you're seeing it as a function in your returned objected because that's exactly how you defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `()` to execute your function.  But you can simplify it further by just assigning the value of your `replace()` directly, like this:

```
let song = {
     name: document.getElementById('title').value,//Line 1
     artist: document.getElementById('yr').value,//Line 2
     path: fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
};
```

If you're committed to using the function in the way you defined it, you can do this:

```
let song = {
     name: document.getElementById('title').value,//Line 1
     artist: document.getElementById('yr').value,//Line 2
     path: function () {//Line 3
        var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        return filename;
     }()
};
```

Note the extra `()` after the `path` function definition.

Comment: Yeah okay I just tried this and it easily worked, Thanks a lot @Marc !!!